# PowerShell script to enable email forwarding for 50 users

Tags: powershell, office365

Here is the code, I need to import the CSV and enable forward to some other email address from office 365

```
$creds = Get-Credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ `
                         -Credential $creds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-Module MSOnline

Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds

Import-PSSession $Session





$emails = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Lev\Desktop\Email.csv"

ForEach($mail in $emails)
{

Set-Mailbox $mail.Work_email -ForwardingSmtpAddress $mail.home_email -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true 

}
```

I fixed the code and now this is a working code.

Comment: What is your question here ? Is the code above not working ?

Comment: I believe the problem is with the parameters in the Set-Mailbox line. Should be: `Set-Mailbox -Identity $email.Work_email -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true  -ForwardingSMTPAddress $email.home_email`. If that is not your problem, please elaborate by editing the question. In that case, also provide some of the email-test.csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment as proper answer:

You need to change the line

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity $email.Work_email -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true $email.home_email -ForwardingSMTPAddress $true
```

to

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity $email.Work_email -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSMTPAddress $email.home_email
```

See example 1 in [Set-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#examples)

Comment: In the end it worked before you answered, I fixed the mistake and after I came to here, i saw that you write the same  :)
 `Set-Mailbox $mail.Work_email -ForwardingSmtpAddress $mail.home_email -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true `

But thank you @theo very much for your help !

Comment: @WebsGhost If the answer is correct you should mark it as such by clicking on the tick next to the question

Answer (score 0):

$emails = Import-CSV C:\path\to\csv.csv
ForEach($email in $emails)
{
Set-Mailbox $email.email1 -ForwardingAddress $email.email2 -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).